# mix ecto.create connection refused

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I received this error when trying to run `mix ecto.create`:

> 13:27:47.442 [error] GenServer #PID<0.3189.0> terminating
>       ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432):connection refused - :econnrefused
>       (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:148:DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
>       (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
>       (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
>       Last message: nil
>       State: Postgrex.Protocol
>       ** (Mix) The database for Hello.Repo couldn't be created: an exception was raised:
>       ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
>           (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:148: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
>           (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
>           (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that the postgresql server is running. The easiest way to this on mac OS X is through brew.

Run the command `brew services start postgresql` and you should see the result:

`==> Successfully started postgresql (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)`

Answer (score 0):

do you have Postgres locally installed in your machine? This error mostly comes when you don't have Postgres installed.

Use these commands to install Postgres

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error when [creating a Phoenix application](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/up_and_running.html), make sure to install PostgreSQL database.

### [Install PostgreSQL on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL)

To install the server locally use the command line and type:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Then create a new PostgreSQL user (role) called "postgres" with password "postgres"

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

Enter below command in psql prompt which opened.

```
\password postgres
```

Enter Control+D to exit the prompt and run `mix ecto.create` again. It should work this time.