# mix ecto.create can't connect to Postgres even though Postgres is running and the credentials are correct

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I created a new Phoenix project and checked the credentials in `config/dev.exs`, which are:

```
config :blog, Blog.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "blog_dev",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10
```

Now, the database `blog_dev` does not exist, but it's my (total beginner level) understanding that `mix ecto.create` should create it if it does not already exist. So I ran:

`mix ecto.create`

Which gave me the error

```
localhost:blog alex$ mix ecto.create
warning: found quoted keyword "test" but the quotes are not required. Note that keywords are always atoms, even when quoted. Similar to atoms, keywords made exclusively of Unicode letters, numbers, underscore, and @ do not require quotes
  mix.exs:57


18:04:24.675 [error] GenServer #PID<0.212.0> terminating
** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp recv: closed
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:163: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
** (Mix) The database for Blog.Repo couldn't be created: an exception was raised:
    ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp recv: closed
        (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:163: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
        (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

[This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44358515/mix-ecto-create-connection-refused) suggests that this kind of error usually occurs when Postgres is not running. So I checked like so:

```
localhost:blog alex$ brew services list
Name                       Status  User Plist
postgresql                 started
```

I also considered that my credentials were incorrect, so I tried manually logging into Postgres with the credentials in `config/dev.exs` like so:

```
localhost:blog alex$ psql postgres postgres -W
Password: 
psql (11.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

The password I typed was 'postgres'. Does anyone have any suggestions about what could be going on here? Thanks!

Comment: *I created a new Phoenix project* -- Not enough info.

Comment: Starting with v10, PostgreSQL uses `5433` port for encrypted connections by default. Check your `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf` for `port` entry.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, I don't think it is a port problem.  When I use the wrong port, I get the error: *(DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:55): connection refused - :econnrefused*

Comment: @7stud I meant I created my project by running the command `mix phx.new blog`, sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Postgres 11.4 pulled from docker and Phoenix 1.4.9 running on Elixir 1.8.2/OTP 21 work fine when the app is connecting to the default 5432 port.

```sh
docker pull postgres:11.4
docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d -p 5434:5432 postgres:11.4
mix archive.install hex phx_new 1.4.9
mix phx.new blog
mix ecto.create

# Compiling 13 files (.ex)
# Generated blog app
# The database for Blog.Repo has been created
```

Note that in the example above the local port `5434` is mapped to container's port `5432` where postgres listens. If we now change the mapping to `5434:5788`, `5788` being a random port value not used by postgres, the setup breaks with an error similar to what you see.

```sh
docker container stop pg-docker
docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d -p 5434:5788 postgres:11.4
mix ecto.create

# 11:25:32.876 [error] GenServer #PID<0.217.0> terminating
# ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp recv: closed
#     (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:87: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
#     (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
#     (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
# Last message: nil
# State: Postgrex.Protocol
# ** (Mix) The database for Blog.Repo couldn't be created: killed
```

Which means that your app tries establish a TCP connection to a closed port.

In other words, check your postgres config and make sure the port you are connecting to is the one where postgres listens.

Answer (score 0):

> Which gave me the error
>
> localhost:blog alex$ mix ecto.create warning: found quoted keyword
>   "test" but the quotes are not required.    mix.exs:57

The first thing you should do is fix all the warnings/errors that you are able to.  So, what does your mix.exs file look like at line 57?

You need to do four things to create your database:

1) In mix.exs:

```
  defp deps do [
    ...
    ...
    {:ecto_sql, "3.0.3"},  # whatever versions you want here
    {:postgrex, "0.14.1"},
    {:phoenix_ecto, "~>4.0"}
  ]
```

2) In `config/config.exs`:

```
config :blog,
  ecto_repos: [Blog.Repo]
```

3) In `config/dev.exs`:

```
config :blog, Blog.Repo,
  database: "blog_dev",

  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",

  hostname: "localhost",
  port: "5432",

  show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
  pool_size: 10
```

You need to figure out what port your postgres server is running on.  Mine  (Postgres.app) runs on port `5432` by default.

3) In `lib/blog/repo.ex`:

```
defmodule Blog.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :blog,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
end
```

4) `.../phoenix_apps/blog$ mix ecto.create`

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the warning is likely provoked by quotes around the key `test` in aliases of `mix.exs`: `"test":  ["ecto.drop", "ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "test"]` should be `test: [...]`.

Comment: I have all of that stuff and I am running Postgres on the default port (5432) and I get the exact same error :(